# Multiple calculations in SQL statement - different result

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, case

I'm trying to solve why sql statement in vb.net code gives me different results than in sql server.
My code:

```
                            strsql = "SELECT DISTINCT DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,lgdatm,-1)) as lgMon, Avi,  SUM((ProcElaps / 60) / Emplo) as Util, Effi, SUM(((ProcElaps / 60) * Avi) / Emplo) as DayProd, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount FROM " & _
        "(SELECT DISTINCT lgdatm, Emplo, SUM((Emplo - (NonProcElaps / 60)) / Emplo) as Avi, SUM((ProcElaps / 60) / (Emplo- (NonProcElaps / 60))) as Effi, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount FROM " & _
    "(SELECT DISTINCT lgdatm, SUM(460 * lgdat * EmpCount) as Emplo, NonProcElaps, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount FROM " & _
    "(SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(LogDate) AS lgdatm, " & _
                    "Count(DISTINCT " & _
                    "CASE WHEN (ActivityCategory = @ActivAc) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN Enumber ELSE '0' END) AS EmpCount, " & _
                    "Count(DISTINCT " & _
                    "CASE WHEN (ActivityCategory = @ActivAc) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN LogDate ELSE LogDate END) lgdat, " & _
                    "Count(" & _
                    "CASE WHEN (ActivityCategory = @ActivAc) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN FirstActivity ELSE '0' END) AS ProcCount, " & _
                    "Count(" & _
                    "CASE WHEN (ActivityCategory = @ActivAcnon) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN FirstActivity ELSE '0' END) AS NonProcCount, " & _
                    "SUM(" & _
                    "CASE WHEN  (ActivityCategory = @ActivAc) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN Elapsed ELSE '0' END) ProcElaps, " & _
                    "SUM(" & _
                    "CASE WHEN  (ActivityCategory = @ActivAcnon) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN Elapsed ELSE '0' END) NonProcElaps " & _
    "FROM tblMain WHERE MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat " & _
    "GROUP BY MONTH(LogDate)) AS T1 " & _
    "Group By lgdatm, EmpCount, NonProcElaps, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount) AS T2 " & _
    "Group BY lgdatm, Emplo, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount) As T3 " & _
    "Group BY lgdatm, Avi, Effi, ProcElaps, ProcCount, NonProcCount Order By DayProd, Util, Avi, Effi"
                        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, cnn)
                        Dim ds As New DataSet()
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivAc", proc)
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivAcnon", nonproc)
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LGDat", Mon)
                        da.Fill(ds, "Productivity")
                        txtDayProductivity.Text = Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4).ToString(), "Percent")
                        txtAvailabilityTeam.Text = Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1).ToString(), "Percent")
                        txtEfficiencyTeam.Text = Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString(), "Percent")
                        txtUtilizationTeam.Text = Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString(), "Percent")
                        txtTotLogg.Text = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(5).ToString()) / 60
                        txtTotalTimeLogged.Text = (CDec(txtTotLogg.Text).ToString("N2")) & " mins"
                        txtAllProcess.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(6).ToString()
                        txtAllNonProcess.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(7).ToString()
```

When I add each thread to a separate query, the results are quite different from those that  I get during enforcement of this code. Do you think it is because of CASE, or I'm wrongly using CASE.

("@LGDat", Mon) - Mon is current Month (number)
("@ActivAc", proc) - String 'Process'
("@ActivAcnon", nonproc) - String 'Non-Process'

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try and reduce your query in size - this will help to isolate and solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out the difference, run [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181091.aspx) and run your vb.net code to check what query is finally going to sql server.

Comment: My app is already running with multipleusers (already implemented, I'm making only things for the reporting module), however, I did this exercise according to your suggestion and this query goes through the sql profiler. (RPC:Completed)

Comment: Have you checked the query in TextData column? This column will tell you what exactly is vb.net sending to sql server to execute.

Comment: Yes, 

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,lgdatm,-1))... (too long)

And this is my whole query with each CASE, SUM etc.

Comment: So is it exactly same as that of what you are running directly in sql server.

Comment: This one - yes. e.g for NonProcCount result is 31639, But when I run query only for column NonProcCount:
SELECT COUNT(FirstActivity)
from tblMain
WHERE MONTH(LogDate) = 6 and ActivityCategory = 'Non-Process'
I get result = 3395 items which is correct.

Comment: So are you saying the query which you see in profiler is exactly the same as that of what you run manually, yet the results aren't the same.

Comment: Indeed. I downloaded full table to excel to check with the pivot table for the result - and again - result are not the same. I do not know why this query multiplies the results. For sure it's to big.

Comment: Okay. I know the answere.... stupid me....
I used:
Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (ActivityCategory = @ActivAc) AND (MONTH([LogDate]) = @LGDat) THEN [ID] ELSE '0' END) AS ProcCount,

Where I put DISTINCT and [ID] instead of [FirstCategory]

Thank you very much for your help. And for the lesson with SQL profiler, now I will start to use it on daily basis ;)